# Changing line graph characteristics to notify that those values are predictions

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following data and want to draw a line graph using ggplot2. The data consists of data for five days, with days thursday and friday being predictions. How can I go about creating some scheme to dash the line from thursday to friday (or different color background) so that I have a visual way to represent that those values are predictions.

Sample data:

```
df = data.frame(date=c("mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri"),
                gals=c(4,6,2,5,3),
                cups=c(30,25,27,22,25))
df
library(reshape)
d = melt(df, id="date")
d
ggplot(d, aes(date, value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + geom_line(lwd=1.15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to plot 2 lines like this, and subset the data for each. Remember to add a point to the "known" series so that it joins up with the "unknown" data:

```
require(reshape)
df = data.frame(date=c("mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri"),
            gals=c(4,6,2,5,3),
            cups=c(30,25,27,22,25))

d = melt(df, id="date")
# select the points you know + 1 to join up the line
known<-d[which(d$date %in% c("mon","tues","wed","thurs")),]
# select the points you don't know
unknown<-d[which(d$date %in% c("thurs","fri")),]

ggplot() + 
   geom_line(data=known, aes(x=date, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
# use linetype=2 for a dotted line
geom_line(data=unknown, aes(x=date, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable), linetype=2) + 
 # this is to make the days display in order
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri"))
```

[image: plot]